# Es necesario escribir DELIMITER para crear un trigger o para crear un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hago esta pregunta porque yo ejecuté un trigger sin el DELIMITER y funcionó (en MySQL)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> El objetivo del comando `DELIMITER` es mantener abierta la creación de las sentencias que han de componer a los procedimientos para evitar se terminen antes de tiempo, ¿pero por qué?

**PROCEDIMIENTOS ALMACENADOS**

Cuando escribimos una sentencia regular en MySQL, tenemos algo como esto:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla;
```

Donde claramente notamos que el símbolo que indica el término de la misma es el **`;`**

Ahora en el caso de la creación de un *PA*, tenemos esto:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE extraeUsuario(IN idUser INT)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = idUser;
    END;
//
```

En la sintaxis anterior, tenemos que el uso del **`;`** como indicador de término de una sentencia se sustituye por **`//`** de modo que cuando estamos escribiendo esto desde la consola, al dar *ENTER* no se termine la creación del mismo en la línea del **`SELECT`**.

Hecho lo anterior, podemos indicar que toda la sentencia del PA inicia donde aparecen por primera vez `//` y termina hasta que este mismo símbolo vuelva a existir.

**TRIGGERS**

**Caso Uno**

Cuando escribimos un Trigger, tenemos una sentencia similar a esta:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER multiplicaId BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET New.id = (SELECT MAX(id) * 10 FROM users);
END;
//
```

Donde del mismo modo ocupamos el `DELIMITER` para indicar el inicio y término de un bloque de código, nuevamente para evitar que la ejecución de este `TRIGGER` se efectúe en cuanto lea el `;` de la línea del `SET`.

Principalmente a nivel de la consola del gestor de bases de datos el omitir el uso de este operador; puede desenvocar en un error de este tipo:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 4

*Aunque pudiste crearlos sin ayuda de este operador* deberías tenerlo en cuenta para su implementación cuando ejecutes la creación de estas estructuras y tengan en ellas mismas el uso de `BEGIN` y `END`.

**Caso 2**

Un `TRIGGER` puede ser explícitamente creado sin la necesidad de los `DELIMITER` de inicio y fin cuando carece de las instrucciones: `BEGIN` y `END` lo cual nos indica que la sentencia tiene una estructura simple.

*El siguiente `trigger` podrá ser creado sin el uso del delimitador*

```
CREATE TRIGGER multiplicaIds BEFORE INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW 
        SET New.id = (SELECT MAX(id) * 10 FROM users);
```

**USO DE `BEGIN` y `END`**

Una forma de identificar si requerimos una estructura compleja y que por ende necesitará de `BEGIN` y de `END` es si por ejemplo tendremos múltiples sentencias `SELECT` dentro del mismo PA, por ejemplo:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE filtraDatos(IN id1 INT, IN id2 INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id = id1;
    SELECT * FROM tabla2 WHERE id = id2;
END;
//
```

Mismo `PA` al que invocamos de este modo:

```
CALL filtraDatos(1, 2);
```

**Referencias**

- [`DELIMITER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_delimiter)

Comment: Haaa... Eso quiere decir que lo pude ejecutar porque mi sentencia era simple, pero ahora me surge la pregunta... que factores determinan que la estructura de una sentencia sea simple o compleja. De antemano gracias!

Answer (score 10):

## DELIMITER:

Se refiere a un ***delimitador*** para nuestras consultas `SQL`,  permite decirle a `MySQL` que todo antes de un delimitador forma parte de un solo **bloque de codigo**, tu puedes elegir cualquier ***delimitador***.

**Dato adicional y para tener en cuenta:**

Normalmente se usan al definir funciones, procedimientos almacenados y disparadores en los que debe definir varias instrucciones. Usted define un `delimitador` diferente, como **`$$`**, que se utiliza para definir el final de todo el ***procedimiento***, pero dentro de él, las declaraciones individuales terminan en`**;**` De esa manera, cuando el código se ejecuta en el cliente `mysql`, el cliente puede decir dónde termina todo el ***procedimiento*** y ejecutarlo como una unidad en lugar de ejecutar las declaraciones individuales en su interior. 
Tenga en cuenta que la palabra clave `DELIMITER` es una función de la línea de comandos del cliente `mysql` (y algunos otros clientes) solamente y no una característica normal del lenguaje `MySQL`. No funcionará si intentas pasarlo a través de un lenguaje de programación `API` a `MySQL`. Algunos otros clientes como `PHPMyAdmin` tienen otros métodos para especificar un delimitador no predeterminado.