# Llave primaria AI no lleva la cuenta de los registros?

Tags: mysql, sql

Mi problema es el siguiente: estoy creando una tabla en la que no quiero colocar la llave primaria ni mucho menos, pero a la hora de visualizarla querría que esta `id` (PK) se mostrara para poder tener algo de orden. Por lo que decidí hacer un campo `idImagen` autoincrementable. Pero el problema radica en que cuando agrego registros, esta columna no tiene en cuenta el registro mas cercano.

Colocando un ejemplo puedo decir que se crearon los registros *1, 2, 3 y 4*, pero luego elimino los registros *3 y 4*. Al agregar nuevos registros, estos no toman los valores de *3 y 4* (siguiendo con la secuencia), sino que continúan donde quedo el conteo anterior quedando los registros *1, 2 y 5*.

Aquí les muestro una foto donde agregue 9 registros y luego elimine 6. El siguiente se agregó automáticamente con el numero `10`.

[image: Ejemplo]

Lo que yo quiero es que se creen los registros de manera contigua al número más cercano.

Basándonos en el ejemplo anterior, si elimino los registros del 4 al 9, los nuevos registros deberían repetir estos `id` ya que se encuentran libres a partir del 3.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Ese es el comportamiento normal. Los autoincrement nunca buscan huecos, siempre siguen desde la última posición.

El motivo es rendimiento. Para que los incrementos lograran lo que pides, tendrían que hacer una de estas dos cosas:

- Escanear la tabla en busca del primer registro libre
- Llevar una lista de Ids libres

Todo esto penalizaría los Inserts, así que no se hace.

Si quieres ver un secuencial en una query tienes dos opciones:

A) Si quieres tener algo almacenado: antes de insertar, miras tú si hay un hueco y utilizas ese número. Pero aquí podrías tener problemas si dos INSERTs suceden más o menos al mismo tiempo. No es recomendado porque penalizas los inserts.

B) Si solo quieres verlo como resultado (sin guardar datos), podrías utilizar el método descrito [aquí](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/)

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT idImagen
    ,rutaImagen
    ,(@row_number: = @row_number + 1) AS num
FROM miTabla;
```

En cualquier caso, el hecho de que haya huecos no debería importarte. Piensa en una tabla donde la primary key es un identificador de pasaporte. Si das de alta varios pasaportes, seguro que tendrás huecos entre ellos, pero seguro que en este caso lo verías normal.

Otro ejemplo: una tabla de 'sexos', donde la primary key es un IdSexo y los valores que insertas son 'H' y 'M'. Entre la H y la M hay varios huecos. Seguro que este caso lo veías normal también.

Por qué entonces debería molestarte en caso de que el Id sea un numérico?

No tienes desventaja de ningún tipo por el hecho de que haya huecos. No pierdes espacio (o mejor dicho, pierdes el mismo espacio que perderías reutilizando un Id), y los inserts van más rápido.

En definitiva, no intentes arreglar algo que no es un problema.

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto, y esta respuesta me parece interesante. Como la ejecuto o donde la meto para que funcione automáticamente? Me toca llamar a un método dentro la columna de idImagen?

Comment: No puedes usarlo en esa columna, este ejemplo era sólo por si querías 'visualizar' un secuencial. Pero esos datos no se pueden llegar a almacenar. En cualquier caso, que haya huecos no tiene que suponerte ningún problema y es algo totalmente normal

Answer (score 1):

Originalmente te diría que eso que muestras es el comportamiento de una columna que posee el atributo de `AUTO_INCREMENT` donde va a tomar el último valor insertado o que existía y de ahí en adelante sumará 1 para generar el siguiente registro de manera secuencial.

Ahora si lo que deseas es que la numeración solo tome en cuenta el último valor que aún existe en tu tabla, descartando a los demás eliminados y de ahi ir aumemntando el valor de los registros entonces tal vez te convenga un TRIGGER que vigile dicha acción; de esta forma

**Ejemplo**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER aumentaValor BEFORE INSERT ON tuTabla
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET New.id = (SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM tuTabla);
    END;
//
```

- Verificamos antes del evento `INSERT` en la tabla `tuTabla`
- Establecemos que la columna `id` en su valor nuevo o que será registrado sea igual al máximo id encontrado en tu misma tabla y de ahí le sumamos 1, para que de esta forma se mantenga el comportamiento del `AUTO_INCREMENT`

**Referencia**

- [Triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)
- [Lectura de interés](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286204/es-necesario-escribir-delimiter-para-crear-un-trigger-o-para-crear-un-procedimie/286207#286207)

Comment: Esta formula donde la almaceno y como la llamo desde la columna para que esta la ejecute?

Comment: @MaxJimenez se crea desde tu gestor y no es necesario invocarlo tu, el trigger se ejecuta en automático

Comment: Esta solución, es mejor que la anterior, pero hará que tengas el mismo "problema" (o muy parecido), ya que no rellenará los huecos de los valores eliminados, sino que continuará después del mayor encontrado en ese momento (en ciertos casos funcionará, si eliminas los más grandes o últimos)...

Answer (score 0):

La base del problema es la generación automática del "autoincrement", y las eliminaciones de registros existentes, haciendo que se pierda esa idea de tener valores consecutivos en ese indice virtual que deseas.

Una solución sería eliminar huecos generados en las eliminaciones o en las creaciones nuevas. La siguiente estrategia permite "regenerar" ese campo después de cada eliminación y creación (necesario porque tienes un auto increment en ese campo)

```
UPDATE a
SET a.idImagen=b.sequence
FROM [NOMBREDETUTABLA] a
    INNER JOIN
            (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b.idImagen) As sequence, b.idImagen
             FROM [NOMBREDETUTABLA] b
             WHERE b.idImagen >= 0) 
    b ON b.idImagen = a.idImagen
```

Esto cambiara los valores empezando desde 1 hasta el número total de registros en la tabla.

NO RECOMIENDO ESTA SOLUCIÓN si tu tabla tiene o va a tener decenas de miles de registros (o más).

Edito para ponerte un ejemplo en la web para que puedas ver como funciona.
https://rextester.com/live/OJWW33734

Comment: Se supone que idImagen es una Primary Key. No se debería poder actualizar...

Comment: @julio, ¿Desde cuando una primary key no puede ser modificada respetando las reglas de primary key?  (excepto en casos muy concretos, que no son el caso tratado aquí)

Comment: Algunos SGBD lo permiten, otros no. Pero en general es mala idea actualizar una PK https://stackoverflow.com/a/3838649/7500028. Si tienes la necesidad de actualizar una PK, probablemente no has hecho algo bien en el diseño de la bbdd

Comment: Y además en este caso, donde OP parece querer actualizar la PK únicamente por 'estética' o porque debe creer que así gasta menos espacio, lo cual es falso

Comment: @julio, si, cierto, pero el enunciado ya dice que no quiere ese campo como PK, lo ha puesto por lo del autoincrement.