# #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 2

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Estoy intentando crear un trigger en mysql pero al momento de darle en continuar me sale error de sintaxis. ¿Me podrían decir cual es el error? por favor.

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkPrecio BEFORE INSERT ON productos FOR EACH ROW IF NEW.precio<0 
THEN SET NEW.precio=0; END IF;
```

Error:

> 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 2 me sale ese error

Comment: ¿Y qué error de sintaxis te sale?

Comment: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 2 me sale ese error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando declaras la sintaxis de un:

- trigger
- procedimiento almacenado

Estos se componen de varias líneas lo cual requerirá indicar donde comienza y hasta donde debe terminar, dado que las sentencias comprender su propio punto final cuando vean el símbolo de `;`.

Entonces debemos hacer uso de los `DELIMITERS` con los cuales indicaremos una símbología que nos ayude a que el motor sepa que hasta que no la vuelva a ver declarada entienda que la sentencia aún no termina.

Entonces puedes probar con el uso de `//` del modo siguiente:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER checkPrecio BEFORE INSERT ON productos 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.precio<0 
            THEN SET NEW.precio=0;
        END IF;
    END; //
```

- [Sintaxis de triggers en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- Te dejo [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286204/es-necesario-escribir-delimiter-para-crear-un-trigger-o-para-crear-un-procedimie/286207#286207) para que consultes