# Procedimiento almacenado para obtener el último ID insertado

Tags: mysql, sql

Espero que me puedan ayudar estoy creando una aplicación estoy usando como base de datos MySql.

Mi inconveniente es el siguiente estoy utilizando procedimientos almacenado para insertar lo que quiero es retornar el ID autogenerado por la la consulta que se insertó.

Este es mi procedimiento almacenado que quiero crear, pero me lanza un error

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insertar_Compra(
    OUT _IdCompra INT,
    IN _IdProveedor INT(11),
    IN _Fecha DATE,
    )
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tb_Compra(IdProveedor,Fecha)
    VALUES (_IdProveedor,_Fecha)
    SET _IdCompra = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END;
```

el error que tengo en en el SET _IdCompra = LAST_INSERT_ID();

> **#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'SET _IdCompra = LAST_INSERT_ID()' en la linea 11**

> quise hacerlo como en sql server con @@IDENTITY pero en MySql creo que no Existe IDENTITY.

Comment: Creo que sería  `SET _IdCompra = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: use SET _IdCompra = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() y acomode los puntos y como pero me sigue generando el error
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'SET _IdCompra = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' en la linea 11

Comment: mucho gusto. Una vez insertado el valor en la tabla tienes 2 opciones: la primera es hacer un select max(id) from tabla o hacer un SELECT id FROM tabla order by id desc LIMIT 1;. Espero sea de tu ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por la corrección, ando trabajando en SQL server ultimamente, ahora lo edito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realiza las siguientes modificaciones:

- Quita el valor que planeas como salida con `OUT`
- Cuando una sentencia termina debes colocarle el punto y coma, que es lo que te hace falta en tu `INSERT`
- Para tomar el `id` del valor recién ingresado por tu PA alcanza con hacer un `SELECT` del mismo una vez que hayas hecho el `SELECT`
- También es importante tengas en consideración que un *PA* al igual que un *trigger* son sentencias complejas por lo cual se hace necesario usar los [Delimiters](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286204/es-necesario-escribir-delimiter-para-crear-un-trigger-o-para-crear-un-procedimie/286207#286207) y de esta forma el motor sepa donde inicia y termina dicha estructura.
- Debes hacer un `SELECT` de la función mencionada ya que de esa manera estaríamos haciendo un print del valor generado

Tu PA quedaría así:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Insertar_Compra(   IN _IdProveedor INT(11),
                                    IN _Fecha DATE)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tb_Compra(IdProveedor,Fecha)
            VALUES (_IdProveedor,_Fecha);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
//
```

De forma que cuando lo invoques quedaría de esta forma:

```
call Insertar_Compra(23, "2020-05-12");
```

Y nos retornaría:

> idReciénCreado, por ejemplo 23

Comment: ¿si haces el `select LAST_INSERT_ID()` es mejor que si hicieras un `SELECT MAX(ID) from TablaX` o es practicamente lo mismo? @BetaM

Comment: Una pregunta con el OUT _IdCompra yo quiero retornar id Generado por esa consulta a mi programa de C# donde lo estoy creando. Para luego con ese ID poder registrar su detalle de compra en otra tabla

Comment: Con esto se creo perfecto 
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE Insertar_Compra(   IN _IdProveedor INT(11),
                                    IN _Fecha DATE)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tb_Compra(IdProveedor,Fecha)
            VALUES (_IdProveedor,_Fecha);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
END;
//
Pero no hay manera de devolver el id generado por la misma consulta, por ejemplo en sql Server lo devuelve set @IdCompra=@@IDENTITY

Comment: Gracias esta perfecto

Comment: Var a disculpar eso estoy buscando como valorar tu respuesta y no lo encuentro