# Error Procedimiento almacenado mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado para una consulta en mysql, pero al momento de crearla me arroja error de sintaxis

esta es la consulta

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE mostrarTelefonosValidados(telefono VARCHAR(50))

 BEGIN 

  SELECT n.guia, n.telefono, r.sin_15, r.tipo, r.empresa, r.servicio,r.modalidad,
  r.localidad,r.indicativo,r.bloque,r.resolucion,r.fecha,r.reemplazar_por,
  r.caracteres from normalizacion_telefonos_validar n
  left join referencia_completa r ON
  r.sin_15 like CONCAT('%',n.telefono,'%')GROUP by 
   guia;

 END $$
 delimiter;



simulacion de gestor 

1 CREATE PROCEDURE mostrarTelefonosValidados(telefono VARCHAR(50))

2 BEGIN 

3 SELECT n.guia, n.telefono, r.sin_15, r.tipo, r.empresa, 
4 r.servicio,r.modalidad,
5 r.localidad,r.indicativo,r.bloque,r.resolucion,r.fecha,r.reemplazar_por,
6 r.caracteres from normalizacion_telefonos_validar n
7 left join referencia_completa r ON
8 r.sin_15 like CONCAT('%',n.telefono,'%')
9 GROUP by guia;

10 END $$
11 delimiter;
```

error de sintaxis en la linea 9

pruebo la consulta sin ser procedimiento y se realiza con exito. Les agradeceria alguna guia. Gracias

Comment: Ayudaría mucho indiques cual es el mensaje de error que obtienes

Comment: ahi indique el error. modifique la pregunta

Comment: Tu error esta en la forma en la que formas tu consulta el delimitador debe de ir indicado al principio

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Es necesario escribir DELIMITER para crear un trigger o para crear un procedimiento almacenado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286204/es-necesario-escribir-delimiter-para-crear-un-trigger-o-para-crear-un-procedimie)

Comment: Revisa la sintaxis de las respuestas dadas en esa publicación para los `DELIMITERS`

Comment: respondida y solucionada.

Comment: Solucionaste tu pregunta @AlvaroAliaga??

Comment: si @Excorpion. gracias