# #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'CREATE TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

[image: base de datos]

Cada vez que se realice una venta se debe actualizar automáticamente, las unidades existentes por cada artículo.

Inmediatamente actualizado las unidades existentes del producto, se deberá activar otro trigger para guardar en una tabla articulo_logs los campos idarticulo, precio, de venta fecha y hora del pedido

Adjunto mi intento de la creación de ambos trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_cantidad AFTER INSERT ON venta
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE articulo SET stock = stock -1 WHERE id_articulo = NEW.id_articulo;

CREATE TRIGGER articulo_guardado AFTER UPDATE ON articulo
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO articulo_logs(id_articulo, precio, fecha_hora)
  VALUES(NEW.id_articulo, New.precio, sysdate());
END;;
END;;
```

Este es el error que aparece:

MySQL ha dicho: Documentación

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'CREATE TRIGGER articulo_guardado AFTER UPDATE ON articulo
> FOR EACH ROW
> INSERT ' en la linea 5

Answer (score 1):

Tus fallos estarían referidos a:

- Necesitas declarar un `DELIMITER`
- Quitaría el doble `END;;` que tenemos al final pues ese debería estar precedido de un `BEGIN` y si no pones esto último entonces lo que menciono al inicio esta demás
- Finalmente ese mismo delimiter debe finalizar la sentencia

Entonces debería quedar así:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER actualizar_cantidad AFTER INSERT ON venta
    FOR EACH ROW
        UPDATE articulo SET stock = stock -1 WHERE id_articulo = NEW.id_articulo;

CREATE TRIGGER articulo_guardado AFTER UPDATE ON articulo
    FOR EACH ROW
        INSERT INTO articulo_logs(id_articulo, precio, fecha_hora)
                            VALUES(NEW.id_articulo, New.precio, sysdate());
//
```

**Enlaces de interés**

- [Triggers en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)
- [Uso de `DELIMITER`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286204/es-necesario-escribir-delimiter-para-crear-un-trigger-o-para-crear-un-procedimie/286207#286207)