# Trigger que se ejecute sólo al actualizar determinadas columnas o campos

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, trigger

Tengo el siguiente trigger en SQL con MariaDB v10.1 como SGBD

```
CREATE TRIGGER tic_bd_compus_bu BEFORE UPDATE 
ON tic_bd_compus 
FOR EACH row 
  INSERT INTO tic_bd_info 
              (ant_centro, 
               ant_usuario, 
               nuevo_centro, 
               nuevo_usuario, 
               f_registro) 
  VALUES      (old.centro_operacion, 
               old.usuario, 
               new.centro_operacion, 
               new.usuario, 
               NOW())
```

El `trigger` funciona cada que se hace `UPDATE` en la tabla `tic_bd_compus` y se guardan sus datos en la tabla `tic_bd_info`.

El problema radica en que la tabla donde se hace el `UPDATE` tiene varios campos/columnas, e independientemente si se modifican o no los dos campos del `trigger` (`centro_operacion` y `usuario`), éste se va a "disparar". Por ejemplo, si cambio el campo de memoria ram, o sistema operativo, igual el trigger se va a lanzar:

[image: ejemplo tabla]

Necesito entonces condicionar dicha sentencia del `trigger` para que se ejecute sólo si se cambia alguno de los dos campos ya mencionados.

Intenté (o inventé) realizar lo siguiente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tic_bd_compus_bu before 
UPDATE 
ON tic_bd_compus FOR each row AS 
IF 
UPDATE (centro_operacion, usuario) BEGIN 
INSERT INTO tic_bd_info 
            ( 
                        ant_centro, 
                        ant_usuario, 
                        nuevo_centro, 
                        nuevo_usuario, 
                        f_registro 
            ) 
            VALUES 
            ( 
                        old.centro_operacion, 
                        old.usuario, 
                        new.centro_operacion, 
                        new.usuario, 
                        NOW() 
            ) 
END
```

Pero esto, claramente no funciona. No conozco mucho de `triggers`, [en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56686451#56686451) me comentan comparar si los campos para `old` y `new` son iguales haciendo lo siguiente:

```
IF NEW.columna <> OLD.columna THEN
```

Gracias

---

**Actualización:**

Acabo de crear esta estructura, creo que está bien aunque al final me dice error de sintaxis:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER tic_bd_compus_bu BEFORE UPDATE 
ON tic_bd_compus 
FOR EACH row 
BEGIN

IF new.centro_operacion <> old.centro_operacion || new.usuario <> old.usuario THEN BEGIN

  INSERT INTO tic_bd_info 
              (ant_centro, 
               ant_usuario, 
               nuevo_centro, 
               nuevo_usuario, 
               f_registro) 
  VALUES      (old.centro_operacion, 
               old.usuario, 
               new.centro_operacion, 
               new.usuario,
               NOW());
               
               END;
               
 END IF;
               
 END
```

---

Comparto SQL de mi base de datos a modo de prueba. (Incluye sentencia CREATE DATABASE):
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jheymejia/pruebas/master/pruebas1.sql

PD: Estoy trabajando con PHP7, estoy abierto a opciones con dicho lenguaje.

Comment: @BetaM `#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 18` la línea 18 es `NOW());`

Comment: tienes dos END; END IF;??

Comment: bueno poco puedo hacer sin la estructura de la base de datos.. aunque sea un error de sintaxis no tengo manera de verificarlo...

Comment: me parece que el error apunta al create trigger: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6234233/4717133

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez sí, me temo que es eso. No soporta sentencias preparadas. Vi a alguien que lo hacía, pero en SQL Server. Igual gracias por el comentario, espero alguien más pueda confirmarlo.

Comment: Pensé que ya había quedado claro que no puedes implementar el CREATE TRIGGER en Sentencias Preparadas.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez gracias amigo, sigo insistiendo, a lo mejor existen otras opciones, no me limito a SQL, el backend lo estoy manejando con PHP, estoy abierto a opciones con dicho lenguaje

Comment: el problema es ahora el ||?

Comment: @gbianchi solo me dice error de sintaxis cerca a linea 18, es decir, donde finaliza el NOW(), pero no me informa nada más

Comment: Si sacas todo el insert, te da algun error?

Comment: @gbianchi `#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 10` la cual es el primer END

Comment: cambiaste esto ||?

Comment: @gbianchi si señor, por OR, y el error persiste

Comment: @JheymanMejia, ¿como es que estas ejecutando tus consultas? El único problema que veo es que en el `TRIGGER` te falta pasar el `serial`, fuera de eso... [funciona bien](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d372b2e4644057136474fe5528bc6d1f)

Comment: @Marcos a ver a ver, más despacio jajaja. No he probado, pero me dices que falla solo porque falta el serial? No importa que en el trigger no lo necesite?

Comment: @JheymanMejia, depende de como tengas configurado el motor de la base de datos, el `Trigger` puede fallar ya que en la definición de la tabla `tic_bd_info` el campo `serial_compu` no tiene valor por defecto. El error que deberías obtener seria algo como `Field 'serial_compu' doesn't have a default value`. En mi demo yo corregí eso, y se puede ver que funciona.

Comment: @Marcos efectivamente funciona tu ejemplo, pero no entiendo el porqué no funciona en localhost, ni en el server del hosting. Actualicé a MariaDB v10.3, pero nada. El motor que utilizo es InnoDB. Me sigue saliendo el mismo mensaje de `#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 22`, es decir, al final del `NOW();`

Comment: @JheymanMejia, podrías mostrarnos/comentarnos ¿como es que estas ejecutando tu consulta?

Comment: @Marcos acabo de solucionarlo, tu código funciona, sólo tuve que añadir un DELIMITER // al inicio de la consulta y cerrarlo donde me generaba el error. Por favor, publica tu comentario como respuesta para darle cierra a la entrada. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @JheymanMejia, te agradezco la oferta, pero creo que no merezco el crédito ya que realmente yo no solucioné tu problema. Recordá que siempre podes contestar tu propia pregunta y marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!

Comment: @Marcos que maquina!

Comment: Ok, estaba redactando una respuesta, y al buscar fuentes, me encontré con [esta excelente entrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/286207/83304) de @BetaM que resume el uso del `DELIMITER` en un trigger SQL. Futuro visitante, dirígete ahí por favor si buscas más información. Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con esta propuesta de solucion, solo se dispara el trigger si los campos **centro_operacion** o **usuario** fueron los actualizados por la sentencia **UPDATE**

```sql
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `tic_bd_compus_bu`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `tic_bd_compus_butic_bd_compus_bu` BEFORE UPDATE ON `tic_bd_compus` FOR EACH ROW

if old.centro_operacion != new.centro_operacion OR old.usuario != new.usuario THEN
INSERT INTO tic_bd_info 
              (ant_centro, 
               ant_usuario, 
               nuevo_centro, 
               nuevo_usuario, 
               f_registro) 
  VALUES      (old.centro_operacion, 
               old.usuario, 
               new.centro_operacion, 
               new.usuario,
               NOW());
END IF;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

La unica diferencia es validar si existen cambios en los campos deseados, y si los hay, realizar el **INSERT**.

Lo probe en **10.5.13-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.21.10.1** y funciona.

Comment: Hola Jorge, aunque ya había encontrado una solución (ver los comentarios) en efecto tu código es funcional, por tanto resuelve mi problema. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder. Y bienvenido al sitio ;)