# Error de sintaxis al generar una función en MySQL

Tags: mysql, function, sintaxis

Soy nuevo en MySql y he estado teniendo problemas para generar funciones, incluso copiando y pegando las que vienen de ejemplo por ahí en internet me sigue apareciendo el error 1064 en todas, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar a encontrar el error, este es mi código:

```
-- creando la función
create function fn_CantidadLibros()
returns int 
as
begin
    declare @c_libros int
    select @c_libros = select(count(*) from libros)
    return @c_libros
end

-- para usar la función:
declare @cantlibros int execute @cantlibros = fn_CantidadLibros print @cantlibros
```

Y mi response es el siguiente:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
 server version for the right syntax to use near 'as begin  declare @c_libros int     
select @c_libros = select(count(*) from libr' at line 3
```

He estado buscando pero no encuentro respuesta, compañeros de mi clase corren esta función así exactamente como está en SQL Server y les funciona, pero a mí con el MySQL no.

¡Gracias!

Comment: No lleva `AS` antes del `BEGIN`.

Comment: Hola!, he estado intentando editarlo y quitando el ```AS``` me aparece otro error abajo, ```"declare" is not valid at this position for this server version```, cuando los corro me salta el error 1064

Comment: ¿`sqlserver`? etiquetaste [tag:mysql] :S

Comment: disculpa, dice ```server version``` jajaj
es la costumbre, nunca había usado mysql

Comment: ¿No será el segundo `declare`? que no es parte de la función. ¿Obtienes resultado de `SELECT fn_CantidadLibros()`?

Comment: No, al ejecutar solo las líneas de la función me regresa el mismo error.
Ese ```declare @cantlibros``` es para imprimir el resultado con ```print @cantlibros```, pero tampoco funciona.
Creo que es problema de MySQL porque en clase vimos esa función y no tenían esos errores, mi maestra usa SQL Server.

Comment: Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286204).